# How to join multiple objects into one mesh without losing rigging?

Tags: mesh, rigging, objects, armature, vertices

I made a low poly character using separate objects for all the arms legs head etc. Then rigged it and parented each bone to the object that it should move which works fine. However, I now need to export this character as a single mesh. But if I join all of the objects together then the armature no longer moves any of the vertices. So how can I merge it into one mesh without losing the armature connection? I still want each bone to control the same vertices as it did when they were separate objects.

Comment: As far as I know there is no automatic way to solve this problem.  The best I can think is to make a copy of the blend file so you have a fallback; then join all of the meshes and parent to the armature using empty groups.  Then edit the mesh, select the pieces one at a time and assign them to the correct vertex group.  If nobody comes up with a better way I'll write this technique up as an answer but let's hope someone does.

Comment: Yea I was hoping there would be a better way because the whole advantage of making a model out of multiple objects is that you can easily parent each object to the bone that should control it. But if you can't join them into one mesh after the fact like that I might as well just merge them first and then do weight painting.

Comment: When you merge the meshes are you connecting the various parts into a single mesh?  If not it might be faster to do what I suggested than to weight paint.

Comment: Yes I'm connecting them into a single mesh

Comment: if you've parented With Automatic Weights it should work after joining, is it not the case?